# Every Time i run the app it gives me an error related to gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

```
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.49" apply false
}


android {
    namespace = "com.example.notesapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        applicationId = "com.example.notesapp"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-desktop:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.tv:tv-material:1.0.0-alpha10")
    implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-material:1.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-material3:1.0.0-alpha19")
    val room_version = "2.6.1"
    val multidex_version = "2.0.1"

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version")

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.4")

    // Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")

    // Dagger - Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.49")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

    // Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
}
```

every time i run the project in android studio it gives me this error

> Caused by:
> org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException:
> A failure occurred while executing
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

I tried checking for duplicate dependencies and toggled the offline mode
still nothing works

Comment: Another daemon running? Try `./gradlew --stop` and try again

Comment: @SimonJacobs Just tried it still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

The Best solution in these situation is **cleaning and rebuild your project.**

If it still doesn't work, try searching for duplicate resources, such as layout files, drawable resources, or other assets, within your Android project.